# Undefined class constant 'VERSION' when using kreait/firebase-php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting the following error when try to send push notification to mobile app using FCM from my PHP application.

> Undefined class constant 'VERSION'
>
> file- /usr/share/nginx/html/project-folder/vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Exception/MessagingApiExceptionConverter.php

[kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) is being used.

Answer (score -1):

Issue solved when I changed version of  *kreait / firebase-php*

```
composer require kreait/firebase-php 4.17
```

Comment: If you‘re just starting out with the SDK, I recommend going with the 5.x versions (at the time of this comment). Also, by using „4.1.7“ you will be stuck with this specific version forever. By specifying `^4.1.7` (notice the caret) you‘ll get The currently latest 4.x version - each 4.x version is backwards compatible with an earlier 4.x version.